# Python Character Creator Program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game, role-playing-game

Q1. Can the following code be made more efficient and simple?

Q2. How is the general structure of the code?

Q3. Would this be better written in def/classes? If yes, what would the code look like?

Any other opinions/ tips are completely welcome. Thank you.

```
# Challenge 3 // Chapther 5 Python for The Absolute Beginner Book
# Python 3.4.3 // MAC 0SX (Latest) // 01.08.2017
from time import sleep 

pool_points = 30
menu_option = None
attribute_words = ("Strength, Health, Wisdom & Dexterity")
attributes = {"strength": 0,
              "health": 0,
              "wisdom": 0,
              "dexterity": 0}
GENERAL_MENU = ("""\t\tMENU
    0 = Exit and Final Result
    1 = Add Points to Attributes
    2 = Remove Points from Attributes
    3 = Print Menu
    """)

print("Welcome to Character Builder!")
print()
print(GENERAL_MENU)

while menu_option != "0":
    print()
    sleep(1) #provides user friendly reading
    menu_option = input("Please select an option: ")
    print()

    #exit
    if menu_option == "0":
        print("Creating Character Profile... ")

    #add
    elif menu_option == "1": 
        print("ADD Points To An Attribute!")
        print("Attributes Available:", attribute_words)
        print("Points Available:", pool_points)
        print()
        attribute_name = input("Attribute Name: ").lower()
        if attribute_name in attributes:
            value_points = int(input("Value: "))
            if value_points <= pool_points and value_points >= 0:
                pool_points -= value_points
                attributes[attribute_name] += value_points
                print("Points ADDED to,", attribute_name.title())
            else:
                print(value_points, "is an incorrect value. Try again...")
        else:
            print("Unfortunately,", attribute_name, "doesn't exist!")

    #remove
    elif menu_option == "2":
        print("REMOVE Points From An Attribute!")
        print("Attributes Available:", attribute_words)
        print("Points Available:", pool_points)
        print()
        attribute_name = input("Attribute Name: ").lower()
        if attribute_name in attributes:
            value_points = int(input("Value: "))
            if value_points <= int(attributes[attribute_name]) and value_points >= 0:
                pool_points += value_points
                attributes[attribute_name] -= value_points
                print("Points REMOVED from,", attribute_name.title())
            else:
                print(value_points, "is an incorrect value. Try again...")
        else:
            print("Unfortunately,", attribute_name, "doesn't exist!")

    #print menu
    elif menu_option == "3":
        print(GENERAL_MENU)

    #if all else fails!        
    else:
        print("INVALID! Select an option from the menu... ")
        print()
        print(GENERAL_MENU)

#final results
sleep(1)
print("-----------------------")
print("Points Remaining", "=>", pool_points, "|")
print("-----------------------")
for i in attributes.keys():
    print(i.title(), "=>", attributes[i], "\t       |")
    print("-----------------------")

input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the overall structure of the code, I would try to avoid the `if`-`elif`-`else` chains. Instead you can use either a dictionary with a keys `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. and with functions such as `exit_menu`, `add_points` etc. or a list that stores just stores `exit_menu` `add_points` etc. in the order and in a particular order.

To go even beyond this, you could add a [function attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses) to `exit_menu`, `add_points`, etc. called `display_name` and generate the start menu by iterating through the list and loading each `display_name`.

Here is an (incomplete) example of what it should look like:

```
def create_profile():
    print("Creating Character Profile... ")

option_dispatch = [create_profile]

while menu_option != 0:
    menu_option = int(input("Please select an option: "))
    option_dispatch[menu_option]()
```

Comment: Hi @Dair Thank you for your prompt answer. Could you provide an example of how this code would look without the if-elif-else chains? As I don't totally understand how this would function? Thank you. Greg.

Comment: @Greg I added some code, basically it is what this should roughly look like if you had only the 0th option.